# Yosemite install no mouse?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, keyboard, installation, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to install a fresh copy of Yosemite on my mac pro. However, I'm one of those with the famously incorrect wiring of bluetooth macs. So the on board bluetooth had to be replaced with a receiver. It won't work until I can get to spotlight and get the mouse paired. So I must install with the keyboard. I cannot get past the diagnostics and usage window because the focus is on a check box. I have tried everything to get down to the continue button and I can't. What's the secret?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I guess this screen is buggy.  I resolved it by disabling and re-enabling tab navigation.  You can do this via the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: Life saver! Thanks, that's a genius solution, just saved my bacon!

Comment: Unbelievable! How is this not enabled by default!? Thanks @rwat

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a wired mouse, a must have backup for bluetooth mouse and keyboards which often fail.

Comment: I was trying to avoid paying $30 for one of those. Guess I don't have much of an option.